# For Nukeface: Zend Framework 2 + Doctrine2 - Blog tutorialZend\Mvc\Controller\ControllerManager::createFromInvokable: failed retrieving

Tags: zend-framework

Following your blog project. Copy/paste code but ran into the problem described below. I would appreciate your assistance with the code that I have pushed to the Git repository Farsideman/Zend-Framework-2-Doctrine2---Blog-tutorial. I can't fathom it even with reading the posted answers to similar questions.

Zend\Mvc\Controller\ControllerManager::createFromInvokable: failed retrieving "blogcontrollerpost(alias: Blog\Controller\Post)" via invokable class "Blog\Controller\PostController"; class does not exist

Thanks

Farsideman

Answer (score 0):

Wow, almost a year, did not realize a question had been posted. Sorry about that.

Hope you figured it out by now, just in case: the problem means that it cannot find the indicated Controller.

This most likely (and most of the times) occurs when an error is made in the configuration of a module or if the files are not in the exact right folders with exactly right capital letters.

So, make sure the structure to the Controller is as follows, starting from the root of the project:

```
/module/Blog/src/Controller/PostController.php
```

Next up, check the `module.config.php` file and make sure you have this, exactly as below:

```
'controllers'  => [
    'invokables' => [
        'Blog\\Controller\\Post' => 'Blog\\Controller\\PostController',
    ],
],
```

Here the `Blog\\Controller\\Post` is an alias (alternate name) for `Blog\\Controller\\PostController`.

That it tries to use the alias (without Controller) is setup in the `routes.config.php` where it is configured that it should use a class with that aliased name and a certain function, e.g.:

```
//routeName: blog
//route: /blog
'blog' => [
    'type'          => 'Literal',
    'may_terminate' => true,
    'options'       => [
        'route'    => '/blog',
    'defaults' => [
        'module'     => 'Blog',
        'controller' => 'Blog\\Controller\\Post',
        'action'     => 'index',
        ],
    ],
],
```

All of the above is present in the "[Configure module](http://keet.me/tutorials/zf2-doctrine2-blog-tutorial/3-config-module)" chapter of that tutorial.

Note though: the tutorial was posted about halfway 2016, here 'n' there it's a bit outdated by now.

Also, as a side, in the `AbstractActionController.php` class, add the following:

```
/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
public function getServiceLocator()
{
    return $this->getServiceLocator();
}
```

This will overwrite it's parent function which includes the giant warning that this function is deprecated and its functionality removed in Zend Framework 3.